# absolute position of element on screen, including (possible) scroll element

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, scroll, position

I want to know when a user clicks within my `$('#content')` div or not.
Sometimes the screen can be scrolled so that the window is showing `$('#content')` a little above or below it's real position. If the user's click is within the div, I flag the boolean `incanvas` as true.

This is the relevant code I've got within the click handler:

```
    $content = $('#content');
    ctop = $content.offset().top;
    cleft = $content.offset().left;
    cwidth =  parseInt($content.css('width').replace("px",""));
    cheight =  parseInt($content.css('height').replace("px",""));       
    eX = parseInt(e.clientX); eY = parseInt(e.clientY);

    inwidth = false;
    inheight = false;
    incanvas = false;

    if(eX >= cleft && eX <= (cleft+cwidth)) inwidth=true;
    if(eY >= ctop && eY <= (ctop+cheight)) inheight=true;

    console.log("inwidth: " + inwidth +", inheight: " + inheight);

    if(inwidth && inheight) incanvas = true;

            if(incanvas) alert ("Clicked within canvas."); else alert ("Missed.");
```

This code works perfectly fine except when the user has scrolled the page so that the `content` div has moved up or down the page. What's a **cross-browser** way to ensure that my variables `ctop` and `cleft` include the scroll in the position?

Comment: Wow. How about just bind `$('#content').click(function(e) { alert("I'm pretty sure that user clicked within div"); })` ?

Comment: No I do need this function because of some embedded editor that *originates* in the canvas but has a position outside it, so I want to make sure to do certain things when the user's click is *physically* in the content div, and not just because it clicked on an element which was a child of something in that div.